# Running a Cucumber test runner without executing the tests

Tags: java, junit, cucumber

One of the Cucumber options is to create a .html report or .json file of the features being run in a given test.  Every time you execute a test run, it runs through the tests and at the end of a run it dumps a json file to a target location.

I was wondering if anyone knew a way to execute the same set test runner to just generate that .json file and not actually execute the tests?  Ideally, I just want a set of .json files I could consume elsewhere or be used in another application.  Or if this is not feasible any suggestions of using cucumber/gherkin to parse Gherkin into a .json file?

Comment: Cucumber has a dry-run option, but I'm not sure that also generates the report. What is the reason you want to generate a report without running the tests?